# Using Databricks/Python3.x ZipFile to extract 7gb file from zip

Tags: python, python-3.x, databricks, large-files, python-zipfile

I've got a large NPI zipfile which includes a 7.3gb csv.  (file can be located on NPI site here: http://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPI_Files.html -- the Full Replacement Monthly NPI File)

When using extractall, every file is extracted to the proper location and all files are correct, with the exception of that 7gb file.  It only extracts to 108.9 KB.

Here's the code...

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(sourcePath, mode='r') as zip_ref:
  zip_ref.extractall(destinationPath)
```

I even added ", allowZip64=True" just in case, but it still only unzips the file to 108k.

Any idea what I can be doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you see any errors when you run this code? It works fine and extracts zip file when I run it.

Comment: Ali, thank you for responding.  I didn't see the notification.  I also never received any errors.  ZipFile did its thing and said it was complete.  Except every time, with that 7gb file, it wouldn't provide the full unzipped file.  I ended up manually unzipping it and uploading it, as I only needed that process completed once.